# Camera focus an object center

Tags: unity-game-engine

Pick up the exactly center position of object in my code i use onmousedown  function inside this  function pick the click position i want center  an object in the screen

```
private void OnMouseDown()
        {
           
        Camera.main.GetComponent<PanZoom>().thisGameObject = ParentThis.gameObject;
        if (_center)
        {
           
            Debug.Log("Show Popup");
            Popup.SetActive(true);
           
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 groundPos = GetWorldPosAtViewportPoint(.5f, .5f);
          
            Debug.Log(groundPos);


            Debug.Log("groundPos: " + groundPos);
            groundCamOffset = Camera.main.transform.position - groundPos;
            Debug.Log("Camera pos " + Camera.main.transform.position);
            camTarget = Camera.main.transform.position;
           
            float mouseX = Input.mousePosition.x / Camera.main.pixelWidth;
            
            float mouseY = Input.mousePosition.y / Camera.main.pixelHeight;
         
            Debug.Log("Mousex " + Input.mousePosition.x + " : " + Camera.main.pixelWidth + " Mousey " + Input.mousePosition.y + " : " + Camera.main.pixelHeight);
            Debug.Log("Mx " + ParentThis.transform.localPosition.x + " My " + ParentThis.transform.localPosition.y);
            Vector3 clickPt = GetWorldPosAtViewportPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
            
            camTarget = clickPt + groundCamOffset;
        
            Go = true; // For Camera movement //!?
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, as I gather you wish to move an object to where the mouse clicks. Is this correct? Or is it that you, on the object being clicked, want to put the object at the center of your screen to be inspected?

Comment: I want I click anywhere of any object camera can the focus  the object center, not point when i click

Answer (score -1):

I would in this case advise you to read more about [Cinemachine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.7/manual/index.html), as it has functionality where you can make it change [to look at a camera target](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.7/manual/CinemachineSetUpVCam.html). Please note that Cinemachine must first be installed via the package manager in Unity.

[image]